# Transform my Samsung M3 External HDD to Internal?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

So I've got an external hard drive which is a Samsung M3 Station 3 1.5TB USB 3 (here is the [manual](http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/support-content/documentation/samsung/product-manuals/M3_Station_Series_User_Manual_EN_Rev00_110421.pdf)). Now I've disassembled it as I could (kinda proud of myself, it's very clean :D) and I've got a HDD which is plugged to a PCB but I don't really understand how the thing is made and how or if i could even put it in my PC. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0r5A.jpg) are a few pics (sorry I can't put them in my post I don't have the required reputation...)

So can I put it in my PC and if yeah, how ? I don't see the power input like on my other HDDs...

Thank you in advance,
Thomas

Comment: "I don't see the power input like on my other HDDs" That's because it got power via USB 3...

Comment: Well I'm sorry for my question actually it was powered like all the others... Did you see the photos ? Because everything showed it was a normal hard drive actually. Sorry for taking your time...

Comment: [Convert External Hard Drive Into Internal Hard Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUO55J0haRI). You need Sata cord and Sata power.

Comment: Yeah I knew that and that's what I wanted to do. Unfortunately my box doesn't allow me to have more than 3 HDDs with my current graphics card... So I'll wait to buy a new one to install my HDD I guess !